# How do I change the prompt of PostgreSQL console (psql) to not show "postgres=#", but "new_user=#"?

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql

I try to figure out how I can open the psql console with a particular user.

Let's say I have two superusers: postgres and new_user. I can see them when I run `\du` inside the psql console.

When I run `sudo -u postgres psql` I can successfully open the psql console, and I see: `postgres=#`

If I run `sudo -u new_user psql` I get an error:

```
sudo: unknown user: new_user
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Even though I am able to create a new database and set new_user as an owner:
`postgres=# CREATE DATABASE newdb OWNER new_user;`

I didn't find a way to switch a user inside the psql console as well.
What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sudo -u` changes your **Linux** user - you apparently only created a _database_ user. So using `psql -U new_user` (without sudo!) should be enough

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you a lot! I managed to switch  a user this way: 1. `sudo su` 2. `psql -h localhost -U new_user`

Comment: There is no need to use `sudo` for this. Running psql as root is a really bad idea to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are right. It works without sudo. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can modify: `~/.psqlrc`

and:

```
\set PROMPT1 '%M:%> %n@%/%R%#%x '
```

- %M refers to the database server’s hostname – is “[local]” if the connection is over a Unix domain socket
- %> refers to the listening port
- %n refers to the session username
- %/ refers the current database
- %R refers to whether you’re in single-line mode (^) or disconnected (!) but is normally =
- %# refers to whether you’re a superuser (#) or a regular user (>)
- %x refers to the transaction status – usually blank unless in a transaction block (*)

#### Colors:

You can even set colors within the prompt:

```
\set PROMPT1 '%M:%[%033[1;31m%]%>%[%033[0m%] %n@%/%R%#%x '
```

- 32 for green
- 33 for yellow
- 34 for blue
- 35 for magenta
- 36 for cyan
- 37 for white

#### An example set with few more options in `~/.psqlrc`:

```
\set QUIET 1

\set PROMPT1 '%M:%[%033[1;31m%]%>%[%033[0m%] %n@%/%R%#%x '

\set PROMPT2 '%M %n@%/%R %# '

\pset null '[null]'

\set COMP_KEYWORD_CASE upper

\timing

\set HISTSIZE 2000

\x auto

\set VERBOSITY verbose

\set QUIET 0

\echo 'Welcome to PostgreSQL! \n'
\echo 'Type :version to see the PostgreSQL version. \n' 
\echo 'Type :extensions to see the available extensions. \n'
\echo 'Type \\q to exit. \n'
\set version 'SELECT version();'
\set extensions 'select * from pg_available_extensions;'
```

which will give you a result of:

```
$ psql

Welcome to PostgreSQL!

Type :version to see the version.

Type :extensions to see the available extensions.

Type \q to exit.

psql (9.3.4)
Type "help" for help.

[local]:5432 postgres@postgres=#
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it is not exactly what was needed.  
a_horse_with_no_name answered my question in the comments.